# validate.js different functions on invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery-form-validator

I'm using validation.js plugin and in the case I want it I was trying to make some changes to it but after a lot of thinking and testing and searching I got nothing , at least nothing I wanted...
I have this code:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: 
    {
        phone: 
        {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 6
        }
    },
    messages:
    {
        phone: 
        {
            required: 'This field is required',
            number: 'Invalid phone number',
            minlength: 'Minimum length: 6'
        }
    }
});
```

every thing is okay but I want it to run some different functions in addition to showing massages , for example when the user type sth less than 6 char , show massage AND RUN Function ONE , if the user type sth except nums it shows massage and also RUN Function TWO

sth like this:

```
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: 
        {
            phone: 
            {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 6
            }
        },
        messages:
        {
            phone: 
            {
                required: 'This field is required',
                number: 'Invalid phone number' + function TWO,
                minlength: 'Minimum length: 6' + function ONE
            }
        }
    });
```

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback `function` instead of a `string` as the value for a custom message. Just make sure to return the message from that function. That way you can do any operation before outputting the message. The callback `function` takes two arguments, first is the value being passed to the rule, and second is the element.

> [**messages**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#messages)
>
> *...Each message can be a String or a Callback. The callback is called in the scope of the validator, with the rule's parameters as the first argument and the element as the second, and must return a String to display as the message.*

```
messages:
{
  phone: 
  {
    required: 'This field is required',
    number: function(rule, elem) {
      doSomeStuff('run before number message');
      return 'Invalid phone number';
    },
    minlength: function(rule, elem) {
      doSomeStuff('run before minlength message');
      return 'Minimum length: 6';
    }
  }
}
```

Check the [**-- JSFiddle Example --**](https://jsfiddle.net/xjsdso1u/) here.

Comment: it is completely working thanks alooot , but I have another question 
Is there a possible way to also run different functions as each condition become valid? for example the user type less than 6 char , then rewrite it and type more than 6 so the function 3 is run , or user typed non digit then change it to digit and the condition is valid so function 4 runs , I mean some how to have success functions but different for each condition , one for success of min length condition and one for success of number condition